# Is it possible to add a ribbon in the background of h1 on every page?

Tags: customization, css, child-theme, html

I want to customize my h1 and to put a ribbon in the background like in the example bellow.

Example: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/

I'm not quite sure if/how it's possible to make all h1s on the website have a ribbon?

Comment: Yes.  It is possible.  It would essentially mean you’d have to do one of two things.  Either a) edit the theme files and apply a .ribbon class to all the H1s you want to modify or b) use browser developer tools to identify the selectors for all the H1s and add them as additional selectors to the examples in the link.

Comment: I've applied the .ribbon class but the problem is that I don't know how to make sure that Wordpress takes in consideration every H1 (the text is different in each page). What I'm having now is a ribbon that is floating beneath the H1 on every page TT_TT

Comment: Cris J, you'd have to edit the theme - it's really hard to answer this for you without knowing much if anything about the details.  Can you edit the theme or can you edit a child theme?  What theme are you using? Can you show us the code in the header?
It can definitely be done but I can't provide you with an answer, instructions or an example without knowing what's actually being worked with.  Sorry.

Comment: No worries Tony! I managed to do it! I added the "ribbon" class to the title in the page editor in the back-office. Worked smoothly. Thanks for your help!